# How do you shorten this unnatural sentence: "The problem is not caused by me 100%, but it is also caused by you to some extent."

Tags: grammar, meaning, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

Two people are arguing about a problem, why it is caused, etc. And finally one of them wants to mean:

**"This problem is not caused by me 100%, but it is also caused by you to some extent."** (literally translated from the source language)

I know that it is two wordy and doesn't sound natural, and native english speakers would have a shorter and a simpler way of saying this. For example, as a non-native speaker, If I try to say it in a shorter way, something like this comes to my mind:

**"It is not me completely, it is you, too."**

**"It is not me a 100%, it is you, too."**

But, I am not sure if these would be idiomatic. So, do you think would these sound natural? If not, how would you say it in a shorter way?

Comment: Asking for people to rewrite something is normally off-topic. It's OK to ask if a particular thing is grammatical. ("a 100%" is wrong, even if you might say it "a hundred percent"; you write just "100%" because "a hundred" is written 100).

Answer (score 0):

You could say

> You are also ***part of the problem***.

This phrase is used in a know expression which says:

> If you're not part of the solution, you're part of the problem.
>
> meaning
>
> If you don't take direct action to make things better you're an obstacle to change. ([bookbrowse](https://www.bookbrowse.com/expressions/detail/index.cfm/expression_number/481/if-youre-not-part-of-the-solution-youre-part-of-the-problem))

Answer (score 0):

Here's a succinct phrase that can be used when the problem is not caused by the actions of a single person.

> You must also / We must (all) **share the blame**

*Longman* defines *[blame](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/blame)* as

- *to say or think that someone or something is responsible for something bad*
  the dictionary offers this example of usage: “He admitted he shared the blame for their World Cup defeat.”